# Seeking in very large files on 32-bit systems

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, large-files, seek

I'm currently having a small fight involving `seek` with a C program running on a 32-bit (x86) box.

Specifically, I don't seem to be able to seek beyond a seemingly rather arbitrary file offset.

If I do:

```
unsigned long long pos = 15032385535LLU;
int r = fseek(fd, pos, SEEK_SET);
```

then I'll get

```
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1000000000000, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77c3000
_llseek(3, 2147479552, [2147479552], SEEK_SET) = 0
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4095) = 4095
```

**TL;DR** it works.

However, if I increment `pos` by just ***1***...

```
unsigned long long pos = 15032385536LLU;
int r = fseek(fd, pos, SEEK_SET);
```

...then everything falls apart spectacularly:

```
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1000000000000, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb771e000
_llseek(3, 18446744071562067968, 0xbfd0f5f8, SEEK_SET) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

I'm completely lost as to why. What am I doing wrong?

The only significant tidbits I can come up with is that `15032385535` is `37FFFFFFF` which seems interesting-ish, along with the fact that the number [seems to be related to time wraparound](http://computer-programming-forum.com/57-tcl/7154380fab1b3a2e.htm).

The program in question is being compiled with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, which proved helpful with actually getting the large files I'm working on open in the first place, but doesn't seem to be making a useful difference here. I stumbled on `-DLARGEFILES -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and tried adding that but that doesn't seem to have had any discernible effect.

For context (because trivia is fun): I created a large sparse file with `truncate` to reproduce the issue on a separate 32-bit machine (perfectly) with; and the program in question is a small webserver - I'm trying to copy some data off a spare computer, and I've discovered that it's *surprisingly* hard to find a compact web server that can handle `Range:` requests and simultaneous downloads. nginx is throwing Perl errors I'm not going to investigate (Slackware packaging issues - nope), Python's SimpleHTTPServer is uselessly simple, and thttpd dissolved into a puddle of mmap errors. Fun day...

Comment: It's not entirely arbitrary, its one byte less than 14GB. That said, yeah. Not sure why this would happen.

Comment: The second argument of `fseek()` is a `long int`, which means a specific (implemented-defined) limit on the size that can be passed.   Simply passing an `unsigned long long` is not the way to get it to accept a larger value.

Comment: Switching the `unsigned long long` to `size_t` or `off_t` also produces `Invalid argument`.

Comment: [try a `long`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek). If your `long` is 4 bytes.. 15032385535 is 0x37FFFFFFF. That's too big for 4 bytes, but I bet it's picking up on the 0x7FFFFFFF, so it works. Add one to that, and and you get 0x380000000, again, too big, but I bet it's getting 0x80000000, which is what? Some negative value.

Comment: See the duplicate. Use `fseeko`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: **Thanks, that fixed it**. Copy this to an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @i336_ no, go see the duplicate question and answers if there is something to upvote.

Comment: Also regarding the other info in the dupe, I was getting -1 and errno=EOVERFLOW when I was using fopen() on the file without `-DFILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: well, alright then! Thanks heaps again!

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to follow if you write the numbers in hexadecimal (or binary).

15032385535 = 0x37fffffff
15032385536 = 0x380000000

On your system, `unsigned long` is a 32-bit type, and `unsigned long long` is a 64-bit type.

The second argument of `fseek` has the type `long`. When you write

```
unsigned long long pos = …;
int r = fseek(fd, pos, SEEK_SET);
```

the value of the second argument is converted to the requisite type. Converting an unsigned integer type to a smaller integer type — here `unsigned long long` to `unsigned long` — has undefined behavior when the value overflows the smaller type, but on most platforms, including yours, it truncates the most significant bits of the value. It's equivalent to

```
fseek(fd, pos & 0xffffffff, SEEK_SET)
```

since `0xffffffff` is the maximum value of `unsigned long`. When `pos = 0x37fffffff`, the resulting value is 0x7fffffff = 2147483647. Note that the call to `fseek` actually doesn't work! It doesn't seek to the position you thought you requested.

When `pos = 0x380000000`, another phenomenon happens: the most significant bit in the truncated value is set, and it's used as a sign bit, since your machine (like most machines) uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation for negative numbers. Thus the resulting value is negative; it's -0x80000000 = -2147483648. This negative value is then passed to the system call `_llseek`, which takes a 64-bit value (even on 32-bit systems). The value it receives is -0x80000000, which strace shows as its two's complement unsigned counterpart as a 64-bit number — 18446744071562067968 = 0xffffffff80000000.

With standard C, you can't seek in a file using positions that go beyond the range of `long`. If you're willing to rely on POSIX functions, there's `fseeko`, which is simular to `fseek` but takes a second argument of type `off_t` instead of `long`. Under `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, `off_t` is a 64-bit type.